# What is a great inventory crusher for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the best way to compress my inventory after a long mining trip? I have 459 iron ore 69 gold, 120 coal and thousands of rocks. Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "crushing inventory"?  Is there something you want to accomplish that building a bunch of chests won't solve?

Comment: Presumably not having to leave stuff behind in chests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to carry stuff to your main base with minimal number of trips you can effectively double your carrying capacity by placing an ender chest at the mining site and in your base. Then you can put items in ender chest and unload them at your base, as well as carry items with you. Also, smelting iron and gold and creating blocks out of them will save you some space.

Ender chests are reusable if destroyed with silk touch pickaxe btw, so you don't need to waste an Eye of Ender.

Comment: Use hoppers to empty your ender chest into other chests.

Comment: @fredley hoppers can't interact with ender chests at all

Comment: @StevenCunningham My bad, did not know that.

Comment: That would be hard - how would the hopper know whose items to take?

Answer (score 7):

Ores and coal can be crafted into blocks, 9 of an ore\coal makes one block which can later be broken back down into it's respective peices.

Comment: When you make stone bricks, you get back the same amount of items as you put in. 4 stone = 4 stone bricks.

Comment: @Coronus crap I didn't know that. I almost never use them, thank you.

Comment: Coal can't be made into blocks yet, can it? Thought it wasn't gonna be coming 'til 1.6?

Comment: @AliceRees you are somewhat correct, it can only be used in the snapeshots at this time.

Comment: @Ender That makes me more than somewhat correct. The snapshots are not the official release, they are subject to change.

Answer (score 3):

Well first off you probably want to smelt that iron ore and then make yourself a set of tools, and armor. You can use some of the coal you got to smelt those ores or you could make some [charcoal (renewable)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Coal#Charcoal) to do the same.

For the rest of it you can just make some wooden chests and store them in there. That is all I can think of for "crushing" inventory.